# Remove function in a class component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am building an eshop and I have stacked on remove the items added to the "Cart" component!
I have managed to add items using React-Redux but not able to create a function that will remove the "Added Items" inside the "Cart". I would apprecciate if someone could help creating the function in order to Remove each item or empty the entire cart from products:
My cart component code is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Card, CardBody, CardHeader, CardTitle, Row, Col } from "reactstrap"
import PanelHeader from "components/PanelHeader/PanelHeader.js"
import { connect } from "react-redux";



class Cart extends Component {
  render () {
    const cart = this.props.cart
    return (
      <>
        <PanelHeader size="sm" />
        <div className="content">
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader>
                  <CardTitle tag="h4">Products List</CardTitle>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>#</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Code Item</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Price Total</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {cart.length > 0 && cart.map((cart, index) => (             
                      <tr key={cart.id}>
                    <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                    <td>{cart.title}</td>
                    <td>{cart.code}</td>
                    <td>{cart.quantity}</td>
                    <td>{cart.price}</td>
                      </tr>))}
                      <td><button onClick ={() => removeItemFromCart()} className="btn btn-danger cart-button px-4">Remove</button></td>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state)=> {
  return {
      cart: state.cart
       }
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => { 
      return {
        addCart: (product) => {dispatch(addCart(product))}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

Thank you in advance!
P.S. Do I need the mapStateToPros and mapDispatchToProps actually for the code to work?
I tried to convert it into a simple cart component and returend me an error. Is it caused because is Redux syntax?

Comment: What have you already tried to remove them from the cart, where is your problem/where are you stuck. Try to answer this instead of asking someone to write you code. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ I have managed to add them through other components using redux but the functionality of the button within the cart: <button onClick ={() => removeItemFromCart()} is not working removing the added items into the cart! I cannot create the function needed for the onClick event within the "Cart" in order to remove items added! Everytime I press the button within the cart returns an error saying that "removeFromCart is undefined! So, I must create a function to connect addd items with the remove button!

Answer (score 0):

My reducer file is the following:

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from './constants'
import { REMOVE_FROM_CART } from './constants'



const initialState = {
    cart: [],
  }
const ShoppinReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  
  switch (action.type) {
    
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const newCart = [...state.cart]
      
  newCart.push(action.payload)
    return {
        ...state,
        cart: newCart
    }
    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
    return {
        ...state,
        cart: []
    }
    default:
    return state
  }
}
  export default ShoppinReducer
```

Comment: Call the initialState and not the cart 
`case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
    return {
        ...state,
        ...initialState 
    }`

Comment: @Karl H ...Yes when I click on Remove button the items been removed from the Cart however, I would like to have a function as said on the title of the question, where I will manage to remove items within the Cart, too!